# Custom Script with <amp-script> not returning height but returns other values

Tags: amp-html

I have amp-script enabled and am testing some examples of what can and cannot be done.

I'm running the following example code:

```
var elmnt = document.getElementById('element-content');
var class = elmnt.className;
var height = elmnt.scrollHeight; 
console.log(class);
console.log(height);
```

My HTML:

```
<amp-script layout="container" src="myscript.js" width="300" height="300">
    <div class="wrapper content-element" id="element-content">content here</div>
</amp-script>
```

In this example, the class is being correctly returned in the console, but the height returns undefined and no matter what I do, I cannot get it to return a value.

It's really driving me crazy and I'm wondering if there are some rules/limits on what I can execute.

I've tried looking for any kind of comprehensive documentation but there isn't much and the examples I have found seem to allow much more complex code to successfully run such as:

https://amp.dev/documentation/guides-and-tutorials/develop/custom-javascript-tutorial/

Would appreciate any insight as this is driving me crazy!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scrollHeight` is currently not supported in worder-dom at the moment. You can check out this [table for all supported APIs](https://github.com/ampproject/worker-dom/blob/master/web_compat_table.md).